# Mapping MPI processes to particular nodes

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I think this question is irrelavant to ask here. But could n't help myself.
Suppose I have a cluster with 100 nodes with each node having 16 cores.
I have an mpi application whose communication pattern is already known and I also know the cluster topology(i.e hop distance between nodes).
Now I know the processes to node mapping that reduces the contention on the network. For example: process to node mappings are 10->20,30->90.
How do I map the process with rank 10 to the node-20?
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not constrained with any kind of a queueing system you can control the rank to node mapping by creating your own `machinefile`.

For instance if the file `my_machine_file` has the following 1600 lines

```
   node001
   node002
   node003
   ....
   node100
   node001
   node002
   node003
   ....
   node100
   ...
   [repeat 13 more times]
   ...
   node001
   node002
   node003
   ....
   node100
```

it would correspond to the mapping

```
  0-> node001, 1 -> node002, ... 99 -> node100, 100 -> node001, ...
```

you should run your application with

```
  mpirun -machinefile my_machine_file -n 1600 my_app
```

When your application needs less than 1600 processes you can edit your machinefile accordingly.

Please remember though that the cluster admin has probably numbered the nodes respecting the topology of the interconnect. Yet there are reports of sensible increase (order of 10%-20%) in performance through careful exploitation of the cluster topology. (References to follow).

**Note:** Starting an MPI program with `mpirun` is neither standardized nor portable. However here the question is clearly related to a specific compute cluster and a specific implementation (OpenMPI) and does not request a portable solution.

Comment: @srini Correct. All the cores reside on the same node and cannot be distinguished with mpirun. OS scheduler maps processes to cores. Process affinity to cores is [a separate issue](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/open-mpi-v1-5-processor-affinity-options/).

Comment: This might come out of the context, but as a matter of fact, Open MPI allows one to specify the mapping of each individual rank to specific core(s) on a given node. This is achieved by passing a "rankfile" alongside the `-rf` option to `mpirun`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I think you meant Open MPI options -bycore,-bysocket. You can also use taskset or numactl commands to bind the processes to specific cores.

Comment: @srini, rankfiles are more flexible than `-bycore` and `-bysocket`. Within a rankfile one can specify that rank `0` should execute on host `A` and bind to core `0`, rank `1` should execute on host `B` and bind to core `3`, and so on. `-bycore` and `-bysocket` can only tell Open MPI how to fill available slots on each host, ranks still go linearly by the hosts (or round-robin, if specified).

Comment: Dmitri, in your particular example, there is no need to replicate hosts in the hostfile 16 times. One should simply append `slots=16 max_slots=16` to each host's description and then pass the `-bynode` option to `mpirun` in order to get ranks distributed round-robin instead of linearly.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to this party, but here's a subroutine in C++ that will give you a node communicator and a master communicator (just for the masters of nodes), as well as the size and rank of each. It's clumsy, but I haven't found a better way to do this unfortunately. Luckily it only adds about 0.1s to the wall times. Maybe you or someone else will get some use out of it.

```
#define MASTER 0

using namespace std;

/*
 * Make a comunicator for each node and another for just
 * the masters of the nodes. Upon completion, everyone is
 * in a new node communicator, knows its size and their rank,
 * and the rank of their master in the master communicator,
 * which can be useful to use for indexing.
 */
bool    CommByNode(MPI::Intracomm &NodeComm,
                MPI::Intracomm &MasterComm,
                int &NodeRank, int &MasterRank,
                int &NodeSize, int &MasterSize,
                string &NodeNameStr)
{
    bool IsOk = true;

    int Rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
    int Size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

    /*
     * ======================================================================
     * What follows is my best attempt at creating a communicator
     * for each node in a job such that only the cores on that
     * node are in the node's communicator, and each core groups
     * itself and the node communicator is made using the Split() function.
     * The end of this (lengthly) process is indicated by another comment.
     * ======================================================================
     */
    char *NodeName, *NodeNameList;
    NodeName = new char [1000];
    int NodeNameLen,
        *NodeNameCountVect,
        *NodeNameOffsetVect,
        NodeNameTotalLen = 0;
    //  Get the name and name character count of each core's node
    MPI::Get_processor_name(NodeName, NodeNameLen);

    //  Prepare a vector for character counts of node names
    if (Rank == MASTER)
        NodeNameCountVect = new int [Size];

    //  Gather node name lengths to master to prepare c-array
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Gather(&NodeNameLen, 1, MPI::INT, NodeNameCountVect, 1, MPI::INT, MASTER);

    if (Rank == MASTER){
        //  Need character count information for navigating node name c-array
        NodeNameOffsetVect = new int [Size];
        NodeNameOffsetVect[0] = 0;
        NodeNameTotalLen = NodeNameCountVect[0];

        //  build offset vector and total char count for all node names
        for (int i = 1 ; i < Size ; ++i){
            NodeNameOffsetVect[i] = NodeNameCountVect[i-1] + NodeNameOffsetVect[i-1];
            NodeNameTotalLen += NodeNameCountVect[i];
        }
        //  char-array for all node names
        NodeNameList = new char [NodeNameTotalLen];
    }

    //  Gatherv node names to char-array in master
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Gatherv(NodeName, NodeNameLen, MPI::CHAR, NodeNameList, NodeNameCountVect, NodeNameOffsetVect, MPI::CHAR, MASTER);

    string *FullStrList, *NodeStrList;
    //  Each core keeps its node's name in a str for later comparison
    stringstream ss;
    ss << NodeName;
    ss >> NodeNameStr;

    delete NodeName;    //  node name in str, so delete c-array

    int *NodeListLenVect, NumUniqueNodes = 0, NodeListCharLen = 0;
    string NodeListStr;

    if (Rank == MASTER){
        /*
         * Need to prepare a list of all unique node names, so first
         * need all node names (incl duplicates) as strings, then
         * can make a list of all unique node names.
         */
        FullStrList = new string [Size];    //  full list of node names, each will be checked
        NodeStrList = new string [Size];    //  list of unique node names, used for checking above list
        //  i loops over node names, j loops over characters for each node name.
        for (int i = 0 ; i < Size ; ++i){
            stringstream ss;
            for (int j = 0 ; j < NodeNameCountVect[i] ; ++j)
                ss << NodeNameList[NodeNameOffsetVect[i] + j];  //  each char into the stringstream
            ss >> FullStrList[i];   //  stringstream into string for each node name
            ss.str(""); //  This and below clear the contents of the stringstream,
            ss.clear(); //  since the >> operator doesn't clear as it extracts
            //cout << FullStrList[i] << endl;   //  for testing
        }
        delete NodeNameList;    //  master is done with full c-array
        bool IsUnique;  //  flag for breaking from for loop
        stringstream ss;    //  used for a full c-array of unique node names
        for (int i = 0 ; i < Size ; ++i){   //  Loop over EVERY name
            IsUnique = true;
            for (int j = 0 ; j < NumUniqueNodes ; ++j)
                if (FullStrList[i].compare(NodeStrList[j]) == 0){   //  check against list of uniques
                    IsUnique = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (IsUnique){
                NodeStrList[NumUniqueNodes] = FullStrList[i];   //  add unique names so others can be checked against them
                ss << NodeStrList[NumUniqueNodes].c_str();  //  build up a string of all unique names back-to-back
                ++NumUniqueNodes;   //  keep a tally of number of unique nodes
            }
        }
        ss >> NodeListStr;  //  make a string of all unique node names
        NodeListCharLen = NodeListStr.size();   //  char length of all unique node names
        NodeListLenVect = new int [NumUniqueNodes]; //  list of unique node name lengths
        /*
         * Because Bcast simply duplicates the buffer of the Bcaster to all cores,
         * the buffer needs to be a char* so that the other cores can have a similar
         * buffer prepared to receive. This wouldn't work if we passed string.c_str()
         * as the buffer, becuase the receiving cores don't have string.c_str() to
         * receive into, and even if they did, c_srt() is a method and can't be used
         * that way.
         */
        NodeNameList = new char [NodeListCharLen];  //  even though c_str is used, allocate necessary memory
        NodeNameList = const_cast<char*>(NodeListStr.c_str());  //  c_str() returns const char*, so need to recast
        for (int i = 0 ; i < NumUniqueNodes ; ++i)  //  fill list of unique node name char lengths
            NodeListLenVect[i] = NodeStrList[i].size();
        /*for (int i = 0 ; i < NumUnique ; ++i)
            cout << UniqueNodeStrList[i] << endl;
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Abort(1);*/
        //delete NodeStrList;   //  Arrays of string don't need to be deallocated,
        //delete FullStrList;   //  I'm guessing becuase of something weird in the string class.
        delete NodeNameCountVect;
        delete NodeNameOffsetVect;
    }
    /*
     * Now we send the list of node names back to all cores
     * so they can group themselves appropriately.
     */

    //  Bcast the number of nodes in use
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&NumUniqueNodes, 1, MPI::INT, MASTER);
    //  Bcast the full length of all node names
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&NodeListCharLen, 1, MPI::INT, MASTER);

    //  prepare buffers for node name Bcast's
    if (Rank > MASTER){
        NodeListLenVect = new int [NumUniqueNodes];
        NodeNameList = new char [NodeListCharLen];
    }

    //  Lengths of node names for navigating c-string
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(NodeListLenVect, NumUniqueNodes, MPI::INT, MASTER);
    //  The actual full list of unique node names
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(NodeNameList, NodeListCharLen, MPI::CHAR, MASTER);

    /*
     * Similar to what master did before, each core (incl master)
     * needs to build an actual list of node names as strings so they
     * can compare the c++ way.
     */
    int Offset = 0;
    NodeStrList = new string[NumUniqueNodes];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NumUniqueNodes ; ++i){
        stringstream ss;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < NodeListLenVect[i] ; ++j)
            ss << NodeNameList[Offset + j];
        ss >> NodeStrList[i];
        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
        Offset += NodeListLenVect[i];
        //cout << FullStrList[i] << endl;
    }
    //  Now since everyone has the same list, just check your node and find your group.
    int CommGroup = -1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NumUniqueNodes ; ++i)
        if (NodeNameStr.compare(NodeStrList[i]) == 0){
            CommGroup = i;
            break;
        }
    if (Rank > MASTER){
        delete NodeListLenVect;
        delete NodeNameList;
    }
    //  In case process fails, error prints and job aborts.
    if (CommGroup < 0){
        cout << "**ERROR** Rank " << Rank << " didn't identify comm group correctly." << endl;
        IsOk = false;
    }

    /*
     * ======================================================================
     * The above method uses c++ strings wherever possible so that things
     * like node name comparisons can be done the c++ way. I'm sure there's
     * a better way to do this because that was way too many lines of code...
     * ======================================================================
     */

    //  Create node communicators
    NodeComm = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Split(CommGroup, 0);
    NodeSize = NodeComm.Get_size();
    NodeRank = NodeComm.Get_rank();

    //  Group for master communicator
    int MasterGroup;
    if (NodeRank == MASTER)
        MasterGroup = 0;
    else
        MasterGroup = MPI_UNDEFINED;

    //  Create master communicator
    MasterComm = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Split(MasterGroup, 0);
    MasterRank = -1;
    MasterSize = -1;
    if (MasterComm != MPI::COMM_NULL){
        MasterRank = MasterComm.Get_rank();
        MasterSize = MasterComm.Get_size();
    }

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&MasterSize, 1, MPI::INT, MASTER);
    NodeComm.Bcast(&MasterRank, 1, MPI::INT, MASTER);

    return IsOk;
}
```