# Can I specific different number of mpi jobs per node?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, mpich

In general I run mpijobs this way:

mpirun -np 20 --hosts host1,host2 ./programa.exe

this command distributes 10 tasks to each node. But my question is, Can I distributes 5 task to host1 and 15 task to host2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping MPI processes to particular nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411763/mapping-mpi-processes-to-particular-nodes)

Comment: What is your mpirun (name and version of your MPI library)? They may be bit different between MPI implementations. Sometimes host1:N1,host2:N2 works where N1 and N2 are recommended cpu count of each node. Sometimes you need to put these into file with one host per line format.