# Rankfile for MPICH

Tags: process, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I'm interested in the issue related to the MPICH. I know that OpenMPI allows you to run programs using Rankfile. The Rankfile contains information about which node/socket/core the specific rank of the MPI process will be bound to.
Is there the same or similar possibility in MPICH? I mean, every MPI process has to be bound to the core, which I select myself and write in the file.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a rankfile parameter in the manual for MPICH's [mpiexec](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www1/mpiexec.html).

Comment: @Arash I don't mean rankfile parameter for MPICH's mpiexec. May be MPICH have features, that can give me same functionality as OpenMPI Rankfile?

Comment: Oh. How about [MPIT_PROCMAP](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Proposed_MPIEXEC_Extensions#Environment_variables_for_mpiexec)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411763/mapping-mpi-processes-to-particular-nodes
Check this out !!!